# I can't add an unallocated partition to my primary partition

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-8.1

I have a 40.00 GB sized unallocated partition and is ticking me off because I can't extend my primary (C:) Partition. I checked on `C:` context menu and it will not let me extend it. I do know that the 40 GB Partition is unallocated. (I also have a 1 GB Partition)
- Joseph

`-- Meta Data --
Version: Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center Pack (9600)
Processor: Intel Core i7
Storage: 1TB (Now 863.21 GB)
-- End Meta Data --`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "Disk Management", unallocated space can be extended to an existing partition. Or, look for some third party tools that can easily move the unallocated space to an existing partition. Try [GPartEd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: It helped partially but I will take it! Thanks for the answer. I didn't use GPartEd.