# Windows 10 Re-Partitioning Issue

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

### Win7 ---> Win10 Partition Problems:

My situation is as follows, I previously had Windows 7 installed and when installing Windows 10 I shrunk the Windows 7 partition and installed Windows 10 to the remaining unallocated space.

This was done as I wasn't ready to manually sift through my previous installation for important documents yet.

Now my issue is that I have since finished backing up my things, deleting the Windows 7 partition, and now need to expand my Windows 10 partition.

This is what my disk management looks like:
[image: Partitioning Windows 10]
.

I need to expand my "C" partition, and then likely use the install media to fix my boot record, but I can't seem to be able to do anything with the OEM/EFI partitions that had installed with Windows 10.

So given the issue at hand, and the fact that **I seem to be unable to move or alter the OEM and EFI partitions** before the "C" partition, how would I correctly expand my "C" partition to fill the space to the left, and optionally, is there any way to remove the OEM/EFI partitions and still have an operational Windows 10 install?

*Note: I have attempted to do this with tools mentioned in the comments, none seem to allow me to expand the "C" partition due to the surrounding OEM/EFI partitions that I do not seem to have the option to move.*

Comment: I'd recommend to use [MiniTool Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) for it. It is available for free and it works for me well on Windows 10. Though make sure you have all important files backed up.

Comment: Use GPartEd live USB or EaseUS partition master free.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't add an unallocated partition to my primary partition](http://superuser.com/questions/826735/i-cant-add-an-unallocated-partition-to-my-primary-partition)

Comment: Edited to expand on a few key points as well as attempts with noted software. Not a duplicate of linked question, and I've made edits to further enumerate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity's sake, I solved this issue by reinstalling Windows 10 after reformatting. This was not preferred but I was unable to find an alternative.

If anyone has a possible solution to this problem that does not include loss of data, please answer and I'll set your answer as correct.